The flutter package Youtube_Player_IFrame is not working for me
I am completely stumped on what I should do. I used the sample code from youtube_player_iframe to play a single youtube video. The only thing I changed was the videoID.
Here is my code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_iframe/youtube_player_iframe.dart';

class Project extends StatelessWidget{
  final String title;
  final String details;
  final String url;
  const Project(this.title,this.details,this.url,{super.key});

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
      YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController.fromVideoId(
        videoId: 'TYX3wGsKpwI',
        autoPlay: false,
        params: YoutubePlayerParams(showFullscreenButton: true),
      );

    return Container(
      height:400,
      child: YoutubePlayer(
        controller: _controller,
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      ),
    );
  }
}

This is the error I get when I hot-reload the page:
The following assertion was thrown building Project(dirty):
Assertion failed:
file:///C:/Users/Emma%20Ude/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/webview_flutter_platform_interface-2.10.0/lib/src/platform_navigation_delegate.dart:47:7
WebViewPlatform.instance != null
"A platform implementation for `webview_flutter` has not been set. Please ensure that an
implementation of `WebViewPlatform` has been set to `WebViewPlatform.instance` before use. For unit
testing, `WebViewPlatform.instance` can be set with your own test implementation."

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Project
  Project:file:///C:/Users/Emma%20Ude/Desktop/My%20Website/flutter_website/lib/widgets/portfolio_content/projects_list.dart:15:9

I am creating a flutter website, not an app so I only have to worry about it working as a website. I tried adding webview_flutter to my dependencies in pubspec.yaml to see if that would help but nothing happened.
youtube_player_iframe: ^5.1.2
  webview_flutter: ^4.7.0


Have you tried rebuilding the project after adding dependencies?

I figured out what the problems was. Someone commented about rebuilding the project, so I just restarted my computer all together too while I was at it. And it works now!

If this solved your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer so other folks can find it more easily. Thanks!

Thank you, I'm new to using Stack overflow!
